# Notificação com Firebase Cloud Functions para dispositivo único

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase

Estou com um problema para enviar notificações utilizando o Firebase Cloud Functions, no caso gostaria que o usuário pudesse enviar notificações do site, hospedado pelo Firebase Hosting, para um dispositivo android. Sendo que para fazer isso pensei em fazer com que o usuário que quisesse enviar a notificação digitasse o email do destinatário, esse email seria inserido no banco de dados, e ao inserir tal informação uma função seria acionada pelo Firebase Cloud Functions. Tal função teria que resgatar esse valor inserido e depois disso comparar o valor com o email de todos os usuários cadastrados no banco de dados para que o usuário de destino fosse encontrado e seu respectivo token fosse recuperado, para dessa forma enviar a notificação para o celular desse usuário. Contudo, não obtive êxito em realizar essa função com sucesso, espero que possam me ajudar de alguma forma e agradeço desde já!

Aqui está meu código:

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
admin.initializeApp(functions.config().firebase);

exports.sendNotification = functions.database.ref("Mensagens/Destinatarios/{userId}")
.onWrite(event => {
  var email = event.data.val();
  var tokenUser = firebase.database().ref('Usuarios/{userId}/').orderByChild('email').equalTo(email).on('value', function() {
    var token = snapshot.val().token;
    return token;
  });
  var payload = {
    data:{
      title: "Nova Encomenda na Portaria",
      body: "Você tem um nova encomenda venha buscá-la assim que possível"
    }
  };

  admin.messaging().sendtoDevice(tokenUser, payload)
  .then(function(response){
 console.log("Mensagem enviada com sucesso: ", response);
  })
  .catch(function(error){
    console.log("Erro ao enviar a mensagem: ", error);
  })
})
```